# Way to delete yaml keys in the form "a.b.c.e"?

Tags: python, yaml

I have yaml keys in the form "a.b.c.d" but my yaml file is in the format:

```
a:
  b:
    c:
      e:"world"
    d: "hello"
  e:
    f:
      g: "sample"
      h: 1
```

I want to delete "a.b.c.e" here and I have around 300 rows of yaml keys in similar format any idea on how to delete the keys?

I know about the del function in ruamel.yaml if it will be possible integrate.

Like Lets say I delete "a.b.c.e"

the desired output:

```
a:
  b:
    c:
    d: "hello"
  e:
    f:
      g: "sample"
      h: 1
```

I know there is a problem with syntax.
The actual yaml file has many more lines.

Comment: Can you post more details? What do you mean by "i have yaml keys" (where do you have them)? Can you provide a example of the desired output?

Comment: I have all the yaml keys in a csv file?

Comment: Do i understand you correctly: You have a string like "a.b.c.e" which represent a key and you want to delete this key from a yaml file? Do you use any yaml parser library like [pyyaml](https://pypi.org/project/PyYAML/)? You should be able to separate the keys in the string with `split()`, then look it up in the parsed yaml and delete it

Comment: Yes but after splitting it I will get a list ["a","b","c","e"] and the format for key deletion would be del d["a"]["b"]["c"]["e"] I do not know how to convert the list into that statement because not all the keys are of same length some are of form "a.b.c.d.e.f".That is the problem I am facing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Yes but after splitting it I will get a list ["a","b","c","e"] and the format for key deletion would be del d["a"]["b"]["c"]["e"] I do not know how to convert the list into that statement because not all the keys are of same length some are of form "a.b.c.d.e.f".That is the problem I am facing.

something like this?

```py
keys = ["a","b","c","e"]
yaml_dict = { ... } # some nested dict

last_dict = yaml_dict 

# search node to delete
for key in keys[:-1]:
    last_dict = last_dict.get(key, None)
    if node is None:
        # key not found
        break

if last_dict is not None and keys[-1] is in last_dict:
    del last_dict[keys[-1]] # delete last key from last dict
    # TODO: delete whole dict if the key was the only key on this level
```

Comment: What is node keyword here?

Comment: sorry, it should be current_node

Comment: The code is not deleting the node and when I print current_node it returns the value of the key.

Comment: That's true, i tried to update my code. However, i did not try it out. But you should be able to solve the problem from here on. Your question was more about how to access the dict dynamically and i thing i provided you with a solution for that?

Comment: Yes, you are right about accessing the dictionary dynamically but the last updated code worked thanks.

Comment: perfect, i'm glad i could help you